# How can I display a text in a C# label like written in the editor

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a C# label but when I use the .Text I can't write on more than one line.
But I would like to write it in Visual Studio and it should directly be formatted like that.
Is this even possible?
Is there a tag instead of the "" which is working on more lines?

Comment: Do you talk about WinForms? WPF? or WebApp?

Comment: @RobertFricke Yes, i am using windows forms

Comment: If your using WinForms then why did you label your question as ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the new line in your label text with `Environment.NewLine`

```
label1.Text = "First Line"+ Environment.NewLine + "Second Line".
```

Also, you must set `AutoSize` property false

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
lblAdress.Text = "Hi" + "\n" + "Hello";
```

lblAdress is my label ID

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string strHTML = "<p>Hello World!</p>";
Label.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(strHTML);
```

Comment: That's not what `HtmlDecode` is meant for..  It would only be useful if you wrote `"&lt;p&gt;Hello World!&lt;/p&gt;"` which is the same string but html encoded

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuider` to format your text to different lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("The quick");
sb.AppendLine("brown fox");
sb.AppendLine("jumps over");
sb.AppendLine("the lazy dog.");
this.label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You can also play with `Label.AutoSize` property if ever you need to control the container.

As a suggestion if you want to have more control on formatting, you can subscribe to a control's `OnPaint` event and use the `e.Graphics` to draw the string you want to apply the formatting/styling.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
label1.Text = "Try"+"<br/>"+"this";
```

You can append HTML `<br />` in between your lines

Answer (score 0):

if it is winform then i will do the following ways.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var sampleText = "hello\nasfasd\nasdfasdfa\nsdff";
        label1.Text = sampleText;
           // the other way to do the same thing.
            sampleText = 
@"hello
world
123";
            label1.Text = sampleText;

        }
```